# Angular - error TS2564: Property 'showToast$' has no initializer

Tags: angular

In my Angular-11, I have this code in the component.ts:

```
export class ToastComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  showToast$: Observable<boolean>;
  toastHeader$: Observable<string>;
  toastBody$: Observable<string>;
  toastTime$: Observable<string>;
```

But I got this error:

> src/app/core/toast/toast.component.ts:15:3 - error TS2564: Property 'showToast$' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.

> 15   showToast$: Observable;
> ~~~~~~~~~~

How do I get it resolved?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you're eventually going to initialize these properties(in `ngOnInit` or somewhere else), you need a **[Definite Assignment Assertion(`!`)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-7.html#definite-assignment-assertions)** for each of those declarations:

```
export class ToastComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  showToast$!: Observable<boolean>;
  toastHeader$!: Observable<string>;
  toastBody$!: Observable<string>;
  toastTime$!: Observable<string>;
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error explains the properties are set to have a type of `Observable<boolean` and `Observable<string>` respectively. Unfortunately you never assign them any **value** thus these properties are actually `undefined`.

To solve this issue, again, reading the error gives us the answer: Assign these properties a value either directly when you declare them, or within your constructor.

```
export class ToastComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  showToast$: Observable<boolean>;
  toastHeader$: Observable<string>;
  toastBody$: Observable<string>;
  toastTime$: Observable<string>;
  
  constructor() {
    this.showToast$ = of(false);
    this.toastHeader$ = of('foobar');
    this.toastBody$ = of('foobar');
    this.toastTime$ = of('foobar');
  }
}
```

or

```
export class ToastComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  showToast$ = of(false);
  toastHeader$ = of('foobar');
  toastBody$ = of('foobar');
  toastTime$ = of('foobar');
  
  constructor() {
  }
}
```

Of course you can access all injected services/values as you like (in either solution). These examples are just stubs obviously and do not really include any logic that you may want to implement.